# Add own host to replicaSet hosted with cloud provider with limited access?

Tags: migration, mongodb, database-replication

So I have this mongoDB (3.0.x) replicaSet hosted with a cloud provider called "NodeChef".

To my knowledge, and scouring the documentation, I have no access at all to the underlying host(s).

I want to add a host which I fully manage on my own to said replica set. I already contacted NodeChef support and asked for the "full set of credentials" needed for this operation. They answered that I should already have everything needed and that they know of customers running such a configuration.

Now, ideally this solution would work for X.509 authentication, but I would settle for storedKey (SCRAM-SHA1), if that is any easier.

Problem in the X.509 case: [For all I know](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/configure-x509-member-authentication/#certificate-requirements), I will have to have a certificate (private key) which matches the certificate on the existing hosts in both O's and signing CA. I can download the public key file for the CA, so I know this is LetsEncrypt. Connecting to the cluster using openssl s_client instead of mongo client gives me the following:

> subject=/CN=*.nodechef.com issuer=/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=R3
> --- Acceptable client certificate CA names /O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3 /C=US/O=Internet Security Research Group/CN=ISRG
> Root X1 /C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=R3

I think I could craft a signing request for that, but I can see no way how to get that signed by the appropriate authority.

Problem in the keyFile case: I have no idea where to get the shared secret which needs to go into the keyfile, despite the support agent telling me I have access to all secrets needed.

I added the new host to the replicaSet according to this documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/rs.add/

The error message I get in the storedKey case is always:

> I ACCESS [conn2119] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for __system on local from client 95.179.166.84 ; AuthenticationFailed SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed, storedKey mismatch

The rs is running mongoDB 3.0.x. The new host is running in a docker image of mongo:3.0.x on an aws ec2 instance.
Would be grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:
Contacting support again, got a possible solution for both:

> Hi Torge,
>
> You will not be able to use the NodeChef SSL certificate in this case.
> You will have to create your own custom SSL certificate and we can
> install it on the NodeChef replica set. The alternative is to disable
> SSL.
>
> For the keyfile authentication which will be required, we can easily
> provide you the keyfile since it is specific to only your instance.